# Azure Front Door to APIM. Rewrite folder to apim suffix

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-front-door, apim

In Azure FrontDoor let's say I have the following domain: https://example.com

In Azure APIM I have an API with the suffix of "test-destination" (so when accessed directly via APIM the url is - https://apim-example.azure-api.net/test-destination)

In Azure FrontDoor I would like requests to https://example.com/test-source to be forwarded to the APIM "test-destination" API

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, it is possible the desired routing configuration with Azure Front door and Azure API Management

Create an Azure front door with backend pool as API Management like below:

[image]

In routing rule, enter the path pattern you want to route `/test-source`.

[image]

Then, configure the API Management instance to route requests to the `test-destination`. In API backend configuration enter the hostname of Front Door instance `example.com` in the Backend URL and the path of the API that you want to route to `/test-destination` .

[image]

To know more in ***detail***, check these references:

[URL Redirect - Azure Front Door | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-url-redirect?pivots=front-door-standard-premium)

[Configure Azure Front Door in front of Azure API Management | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/front-door-api-management)

Additionally, As per [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-url-rewrite?pivots=front-door-standard-premium) you can use url rewrite to change the request path like below:

[image]

Make sure Associate rule set with route like below:

[image]